# Oracle replicat is abending when oracle is having special char while loading to teradata

Tags: oracle, teradata

I am doing replication from oracle to teradata where oracle is having below charter in one column.
->->->
ACSII value for this char is 26 .
I need to replace it with null . In the charmap we have mentioned like:-

```
SOURCECHARSET AL32UTF8
TARGETCHARSET UTF-16
\xef\xbf\xbd  \x20
```

and included CHARMAP in the parameter file but do not know why this is not happening .
I have to mannually update/insert the record in the teradata target Database each time when this
collision happens .

Please let me know in case we can handle this automatically and prevent my replicat from ABEND.

Answer (score 0):

```
MAP ORCLSCHEMA.ORCLTABLE, TARGET TERADATA_SCHEMA.TERADATA_TABLE, 
    SOURCECOL COLUMN_WITH_SPECIAL_CHAR *CHARMAP CHARSETCONVERT,
    TRANSLATECOLS (
        COLUMN_WITH_SPECIAL_CHAR = REPLACE(COLUMN_WITH_SPECIAL_CHAR, '\xef\xbf\xbd', NULL)
    );
```